# Provision EC2 instances if NOT running using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to provision an instance and carry out some other roles on it, if an instance with the same name is not running. I am using the EC2 module to provision and the `ec2_remote_facts` to filter for a specific EC2 name:

```
- name: Gather Facts to check if a similar instance is running
  ec2_remote_facts:
    filters:
      instance-state-name: running
      "tag:Name" : "{{ tag_name }}"
  register: ec2_exists

- name: Display Details
  debug: var=ec2_exists

- name: Provison "{{ count }}" ec2 instances in "{{ region }}"
  ec2:
     key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
     instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
     image: "{{ hip_ami_id }}"
     vpc_subnet_id: "{{ vpc_subnet_id }}"
     group_id: "{{ group_id }}"
     region: "{{ region }}"
     instance_profile_name: "{{ instance_profile_name }}"
     exact_count: "{{ count }}"
     count_tag: "{{ count_tag }}"
     instance_tags:
             CostCentre: V_EFXSales
             Name: "{{ tag_name }}"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  register: ec2
  when: ec2_exists.results[0].state != 'running'
```

This works well, except sometimes I get the following when I display the result of ec2_exists var.

```
TASK [provision : Display Details] *********************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "ec2_exists": {
        "changed": false,
        "instances": []
    }
}
```

This is normally due to the previously provisioned and terminated instance with the same name reporting back with empty status. 
In this case, the provision step fails, even though there are no ec2 instances running with the same name. How can address both conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this condition:

```
when: ec2_exists.instances | selectattr('state','equalto','running') | list | count == 0
```

this should fire when there are no instances in `running` state – list is empty or all elements has `state` attribute different to `running`.